# Importing and exporting execution plan from and to Talend Administration Center talend

Tags: talend

Is it possible to export and import execution plans from and to TAC? If yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it could be done with Talend Repository Manager, a feature I didn't use so far.
About execution plans : [https://help.talend.com/display/TalendRepositoryManagerUserGuide61EN/5.2.3+How+to+create+a+rule+to+migrate+execution+plans](http://about%20execution%20plans)

About Talend Repository Manager : https://help.talend.com/display/TalendRepositoryManagerUserGuide61EN/2.+Getting+started+with+Talend+Repository+Manager

Comment: Is there a way to export the Execution plan from the Talend Administration center itself?